# PHP - Custom query parser

Tags: php

I am trying to make a custom search query parser. The idea is that the user can write specific keywords to search by e.g. artist, color and style. For example if the user searches for:

`style:Emboss some keywords color:#333333 artist:"Tom Hank" steel`

The returned result in the backend would be:

```
array(
    "style"  => "Emboss",
    0        => "some",
    1        => "keywords"
    "color"  => "#333333",
    "artist" => "Tom Hank", // Note the word is not broken
    2        => "steel"
)
```

So far I have managed to do the oppersite - by building a query string from an array with no problem. However I have a problem with parsing a string to an array - mostly due to the fact that there's quotes.

What I've so far is

```
public function parseQuery($str) {
    $arr = array();

    $pairs = str_getcsv($str, ' '); // This bugs me

    foreach($pairs as $k => $v) {
        list($name, $value) = explode(":", $v, 2);

        if(!isset($value)) {
            $arr[] = $name;
        } else {
            $arr[$name] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

The problem relies on the `str_getcsv` function which breaks quoted words if there's no space between the first quote or after the last. It breaks it down like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Some
    [1] => string
    [2] => with
    [3] => but:"some <--- This is the sinner
    [4] => string"
)
```

It works if there's spaces between the `but:` and `"some string"`, however I do not wan't this.

My question how this could be solved by using less to no regular expression.

Comment: What is the reason you don't want to use regex?

Comment: I am rather confused, you want to do something like what google does on their search, is that it ? Like you can search for `php "mysql" site:stackoverflow.com` where MySQL would be the main necessary word and php side word or something like that ?

Comment: why don't you just introduce a delimiter like `;` in your syntax ? example query `style:Emboss some keywords;color:#333333;artist:"Tom Hank"` ..

Comment: @nifr a delimiter (such a `;`) wouldn't be intuitive for anyone except maybe a programmer.  Also, the keywords are separate entities from each other unless the `:` gives it the type, and `"` allows for spacing.

Comment: @PeeHaa Because it can be slow to parse with regex. However if this can't be done (with a decent amount of lines) then I would have to use  it anyway.

Comment: @Prix Something like that, yes (got the idea from Spotify's search syntax)

Comment: @Humanoidism compared to what you have right now I kind doubt the performance would be significant against a well written regex which would be more exact and clear into groups.

Comment: @Humanoidism Is this something you once heard somebody tell you or from personal experience? Seriously, what you want just screams regex. And there is no way you are going to be hurt by any performance hit (if any it is waaaaaaay too small to notice).

Comment: @Humanoidism I think you're confusing the "don't use regex on book-sized-text-blocks" with "regex is slower than other functions". Parsing a 50 character string will have very little effect on what you're doing. I'm giving +1 for PeeHaa's comment, as well as the introduction of a semi-colon, both of which are approaches I might use for something like this.

Comment: So this is the guideline of what you want to do: http://web.archive.org/web/20120704131650/http://www.spotify.com/us/about/features/advanced-search-syntax/

Comment: Regex is fine, this is something I took up as a competition with myself to find solutions without regex :-)

Comment: @Prix yes operators could be introduced later in the works, however that is not a problem to do :-)

Comment: Then why not using `strpos` to find the fields position and then you can simple `substr` the values from it. That is if you really don't want to use `regex`

Comment: @Prix What did you have in mind?

Comment: @Humanoidism check [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), its pretty self explanatory what I suggested, use both to extract the values per field aka year, style, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this... it's quick and dirty procedural code, but does what you want. You'll have refactor it to make it maintainable.

```
<?php
$str = 'style:Emboss some keywords color:#333333 artist:"Tom Hank" steel';

$pos = 0;
$buffer = '';
$len = strlen($str);
$quote = false;
$key = '';
$arr = array();

while ($pos < $len) {
    switch ($str[$pos]) {
        case '"':
            $quote = !$quote;
            break;
        case ':':
            $key = $buffer;
            $buffer = '';
            break;
        case ' ':
            if ($quote) {
                $buffer .= $str[$pos];
            }
            elseif (!empty($key)) {
                $arr[$key] = $buffer;
                $key = '';
                $buffer = '';
            }
            else {
                $arr[] = $buffer;
                $buffer = '';
            }
            break;
        default:
            $buffer .= $str[$pos];
    }
    $pos++;
}
if (!empty($key)) {
    $arr[$key] = $buffer;
}
else {
    $arr[] = $buffer;
}

print_r($arr);
```